# EPS8266 and Secure SSL on STM32F4

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f4discovery

Im trying to implement the TLS library to open a TCP connection with smtp servers and SSL. Im using the STM32 to control the wifi module via uart, how can I implement the ssl library in the stm32 with the wifi module? I'm using EPS8266 AT Parser library, but not sure how to use an SSL Server for it ? Like what resources or architecture do I need to use and do ?

I can connect to EPS8266 using NON SSL connection, what's needed for that to enable SSL Connection ?
I looked for SSL Libraries, would you recommend one for STM32F4 free and open source ?
I would like to know what is needed actually for an SSL connection on STM32F4 with EPS8266

Comment: you need to set the ask parameters using the at comments. you no not need to implement the the SSL yourself. just correctly configure the esp and simple open the connection

Comment: @P__J__ What about the certificate and key exchange and these things ? Just ignore them ?

Comment: it's done by the esp itself on this high at comment level